# What is the most easiest way to search in a txt file by comparing the lines in C++?

Tags: c++

I am writing a code that searches for information about any movie from a text file from the **name** of the movie. The information about the movie there is a few lines and I have to print them on the screen.
I tried reading other things but couldn't understand them.
Also I'm not good with **Do/While loop**, I prefer using **For loop** instead. I tried using **find()** but couldn't get it to work. I am totally a beginner here. And the part in the **if/else** section is not working. I don't know how I can compare the lines. Plus I don't know much other than the basic stuff so most probably I won't know about whatever you tell me.

```
bool search() // The search option to search in the txt file
{
    string choi;
    bool mainFlag = false;
    string line = "";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

reSrch:

    string name = "n";
    int year = 0;
    string star = "n";

    string blunt;
    string blunt2;
    int blunt3;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    cout << "\n Please enter the name of the Movie (or n to skip name) : ";
    cin >> blunt;
    if (blunt == "n")
        blunt = "n";
    else
        name = blunt;

    cout << "\n Please enter a name of any one star of the Movie (or n to skip name of star) : ";
    cin >> blunt2;
    if (blunt2 == "n")
        blunt2 = "n";
    else
        star = blunt2;

    cout << "\n Please enter the year of production of the Movie (or 0 to skip year) : ";
    cin >> blunt3;
    if (blunt3 == 0)
        blunt3 = 0;
    else
        year = blunt3;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (blunt == "n" && blunt2 == "n" && blunt3 == 0)
    {
        cout << "\n You have not entered any of the information to make a search. Would you\n like to try again? If not then you will be sent back to the main menu."
            "\n\n Please enter yes or no : ";
        cin >> choi;

        if (choi == "YES" || choi == "Yes" || choi == "yes")
        {
            Sleep(1500);
            system("CLS");
            goto reSrch;
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(1500);
            system("CLS");
            //mainFlag = true;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if (name != "n")
        {
            if (star != "n")
            {
                if (year != 0)
                {
                    mov.open("movie.txt");


                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++) 
                    { 
                        if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)//npos is used to tell = no matches found
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(star, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(year, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    mov.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(star, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    mov.close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (year != 0)
                {
                    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(year, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    mov.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    mov.close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (star != "n")
            {
                if (year != 0)
                {
                    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(star, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(year, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    mov.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(star, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    mov.close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (year != 0)
                {
                    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);
                    for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++)
                    {
                        if (line.find(year, 0) != string::npos)
                        {
                            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    mov.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return mainFlag;
}
```

Comment: `if (blunt == "n") blunt = "n";` what do you mean by this line? It is simply checking if `blunt` is `"n"` and then in case it is, again assigning `"n"` to blunt.

Comment: Is this a practice problem from a C++ textbook, or a classroom assignment? In either case, all the background material needed to complete the assignment should be covered in the preceding chapter in the textbook, or in the classroom instructions. Is there anything ***specific*** about that which you do not understand or need some clarity about. This question is too vague and non-specific. The problem with all "what is the easiest/fastest/cleanest/shortest/X-est way to do <X>" is that when ten C++ developers get asked that question, you will get fifteen different answers.

Comment: We were not provided with any book, nor it's name from our teacher. And yes I don't know how I can compare any string from the file with any other string in main.

Comment: You should create a function toLower() that converts the input string to lower case, so you don't have to check `if (choi == "YES" || choi == "Yes" || choi == "yes")` , you'll just check `if (choi == "yes")`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. Your code is assuming that you can read the file multiple times for each different situation but that is not true. You must read the file **once** and then apply the appropriate logic to each line as it is read.

Plus `year` is an integer and you can't use `find()` to look for an integer, you need to convert the integer to a string first, I use the `to_string` function for that.

Something like this

```
 string year_string = to_string(year);
 for (unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(mov, line); curLine++) 
 {
       bool name_ok = name == "n" || line.find(name) != string::npos;
       bool star_ok = star == "n" || line.find(star) != string::npos;
       bool year_ok = year == 0 || line.find(year_string) != string::npos;
       if (name_ok && star_ok && year_ok)
       {
           cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
       }
 }
```

The `_ok` variables are true either if nothing was given to search in that category, or if something was given to search and it was found. If all the `_ok` variables are true then we found what was being looked for.

This code is also about 1/10 of the length of the code you had, which is also a good thing.

Comment: Yes, thanks alot but It still doesn't give me any output when I run it for the search function. It's just that I have not studied enough yet. I'm just 17 in my second semester and our teacher has just taught the basics and nothing in detail yet.

Comment: @SaifAliJT You should add some `cout << ...` statements to your code to see where it is going. One simple problem which you don't check for is if `mov.open("movie.txt");` worked. Add some code afterwards like this `mov.open("movie.txt"); if (!mov.is_open()) cout << "can't open movie file\n";`